# Hibernate conditional @Valid

Tags: java, hibernate

Hey guys I have an Event class with a Person object (many to one)
I'm using `@valid` on `private Person;` so that it validates the person object, problem is
I only want it to validate it if another property is set to 1. I.E

```
@Column
@Valid(if(hasAttachedPerson=1))
private Person;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't yet used it but you may use `@ValidationConditionOnUEL` which defines a validation condition based on a [Unified Expression Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Expression_Language) (UEL) expression. This is very useful for checks on properties located anywhere within the bean, multiple properties, or even sub-properties.

```
@Valid
//defines a validation condition true if hasAttachedPerson==1
@ValidationConditionOnUEL(name = "someName", uel = "hasAttachedPerson==1")
private Person;
```

[More details](http://www.lunatech-research.com/archives/2008/05/09/bean-validation-java-ee) available at the "Validation condition on expression" section.